# filtrar tabela com um butao

Tags: php, javascript

Boas a todos,

Tenho uma tabela com dados vindos de uma base dados e queria fazer um filtro através de um botão. Sempre que clicar naquele botão vai mostrar apenas os artigos com a categoria "mercadorias".

tenho este codigo mas nao esta a funcionar. podem me ajudar a edenrificar o erro?

pretendo atraves de um click no botao ele filtre pela categoria.

```js
    var tds = document.querySelectorAll('table td[data-categoria]');
document.querySelector('.btn-group').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var categoria = e.target.id;
  console.log("categoria   " + categoria);
  for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    var tr = tds[i].closest('tr');
    tr.style.display = categoria == tds[i].dataset.categoria || !categoria ? '' : 'none';
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" id="mercadorias" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">CATEGORIA</button>
</div>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>codigo</th>
      <th>Artigo</th>
      <th>categoria</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $cadastroartigo['codigo']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $cadastroartigo['Artigo']; ?></td>
      <td data-categoria="mercadorias"><?php echo $cadastroartigo['categoria']; ?></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Mas você quer sempre trazer todos os dados carregados e através do javascript manipular os dados na tela (ocultar e mostrar determinadas categorias)? Ou, você quer um botão que envie outra requisição para o backend trazer somente o que foi solicitado?

Answer (score 0):

```js
  let tds = document.querySelectorAll('table td[data-categoria]');
  document
    .querySelector('.btn-group')
    .addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      let categoria = e.target.id;
      tds.forEach(function(td){
        let tr = td.closest('tr');
        tr.style.display = td.dataset.categoria === categoria?
        '' : 'none';
      });
    });
```

```html
  <div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" id="mercadorias" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">
    Mercadorias
  </button>
  <button type="button" id="outros" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">
  Outros
</button>
</div>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>codigo</th>
      <th>Artigo</th>
      <th>categoria</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Nasa</td>
      <td data-categoria="mercadorias">Mercadorias</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>NSA</td>
    <td data-categoria="outros">Outros</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas continuo sem conseguir filtrar. o exemplo ai funciona mas no meu não.